# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT from web view when accessing external link

Tags: xcode, swift3, webview

I am currently trying to deploy a responsive website on mobile devices (iPhone & iPad) via a WebView.

Here are some details regarding the app :

- the application's only purpose is to display the webView containing the website
- using the WKWebView component since UIWebView is deprecated in my environment
- any external links should load a new page within the webView
- currently using Swift 3 and Xcode 9.2
- made an Outlet between the WebKit WebView and the ViewController
- edited the info.plist ; App Transport Security Setting > set NSAllowArbitraryLoads to true

source code :

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

// edit the url the app should load here
private var domain = "https://example.com/"

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView()  {
    //delegates the navigation of other urls while still inside the webview
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.allowsLinkPreview = false
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // calls the website in a 'iframe' style
    let url = URL(string: domain)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(request)


}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {

    // outputs are for debugging purpose
    print("webView :\(webView)" + "\n")
    print("decidePolicyForNavigationAction :\(navigationAction)" + "\n")
    print("decisionHandler :\(decisionHandler)" + "\n")

    switch navigationAction.navigationType {
    case .linkActivated:
        print("request : " + navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString)
        self.webView?.load(navigationAction.request)
        return
    default:
        break
    }

    if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
        print("url : " + url.absoluteString)
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

AppDelegate.swift :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

}
```

My trouble comes when trying to open external and internal links ; the app will throw a signal SIGABRT.

From what I understand, this error usually happens when there is an Outlet mismatch, but my project has only a single Outlet (WebView / ViewController). I tried deleting it and re-creating it to no avail.

If the issue is that no Outlet are made between the page loaded from an external link and my app I fail to see how to solve this since I have no control over the website.

Note : when I set webView.allowsLinkPreview to true (in func loadView()), the app loads the new page but takes a considerable amount of time. Also the function webView isn't called a second time when this happens.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit**. as requested in a comment, here is what the debugger throws :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
```

Also, the Thread 1 SIGABRT signal appears to be in the AppDelegate class.

Comment: There should be a message in Xcode's debug console that provides a more specific error message.

Comment: I've added the error message to the main question.

Comment: Your error message should be longer. Could you give it all?

Comment: Note that in case of `case .linkActivated:`, you should before the `return`, do `decisionHandler(.something)`, `.something` being a legit value according to the doc and your needs.

Comment: Closer, but the message we're looking for should say something about the cause of the NSException.

Comment: Ah, there was this part at the end : (lldb) 
Is this what you were looking for ? There is nothing more aside from my outputs from print commands. (I can provide those outputs if necessary)

@Larme ah you're right. perhaps a decisionHandler(.allow) should suffice.

Comment: The message is above the one you gave. It should be something like `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Completion handler passed to -[myAppName webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] was not called' *** First throw call stack:...`. It's explicit.. That's the part we are waiting for. Give it to us.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no such message displayed.

This is all I have : 

navigation request :https://example.com/
decisionHandler :(Function)
url : https://example.com/

navigation request :http://discover.example.com/
decisionHandler :(Function)
request : http://discover.example.com/
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

I am on the "All Output" option, this is all there is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting error message should be

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Completion handler passed to -[myAppName webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] was not called'
```

In `webView(_ webView:, decidePolicyFor navigationAction:, decisionHandler:)` in one particular case you don't do `decisionHandler(someValue)`, that's why it crashes.

So in

```
case .linkActivated:
    print("request : " + navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString)
    self.webView?.load(navigationAction.request)
    return
```

You need to do `decisionHandler(someValue)` before you do the return.

Comment: Thank you, the web view no longer crashes. It still fails to load a new page, but the matter I brought up was undoubtedly resolved.